# Drag down function automatically from particular cell in Google Script

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script

how could I automatically using Google Script to drag down formulas that are in cells Cx to BAx. The whole range with X will be substitute with that code. I just want to drag it down to the end of sheet.

```
function autofill(){

  var ValuesFromC = ss.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  var LastRowFromC = ValuesFromC.filter(String).length;
  LastRowFromC += 1

  Logger.log(LastRowFromC);

  var rangeToFill = "C" + LastRowFromC + ":BA" + LastRowFromC
  ss.getRange(rangeToFill)
```

@ziganotschka edit

I edit a little bit and got that kind of code:

```
function autofill(){

  var ValuesFromC = ss.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  var LastRowFromC = ValuesFromC.filter(String).length;
  var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  LastRowFromC += 1;
  var rangeToFill = "C" + LastRowFromC + ":BA" + LastRowFromC;
  var range = ss.getRange(rangeToFill);
  range.copyValuesToRange(ss, 3, 53, LastRowFromC, LastRow)
```

but it copy as values everyting from the range but I want to copy formula that will be adequate to the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You cannot "drag" as such with Apps Script, but you can fill a range of arbitrarily dimensions with the your range of choice.

> To do so, use the method [copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd,
>   row, rowEnd)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend).

Sample:

```
function autofill(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var LastRowFromC =ss.getLastRow() ;
  var rangeC=ss.getRange("C1:C"+LastRowFromC)
  var rangeToFill="D1:B"+LastRowFromC;
  rangeC.copyValuesToRange(ss, 3, 53, 1, LastRowFromC);
}
```

### If you want to copy formulas only

- Use the method [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) with the [copyPasteType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type.html) `PASTE_FORMULA`.
- Since this method requires the copyTo range to have the same dimension like the original range (column C) - copy the range ( equivalent to dragging the column) one by one in a loop - making use of the method [offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Sample code:

```
function autofill(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var LastRowFromC =ss.getLastRow() ;
  var rangeC=ss.getRange("C1:C"+LastRowFromC);
  for(var i=1;i<53;i++){  //53 correcponds to column BA
   var rangeToFill=rangeC.offset(0,i);
rangeC.copyTo(rangeToFill, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I edit a little bit (code after actualizatioin in main post) and it still doesn't work like I want to

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to copy formulas rather than values - I need to use the method copyTo() instead, which allows you to specify the `copyPasteType` as `PASTE_FORMULA`. I will update my answer - I hope now it is what you wanted!